# Rsync keep in textfile failed tranfers

Tags: rsync, backup

I executed `rsync` in order to backup my files, some of files have not been removed but due to amount of output shown by rsync, I want to keep the failed tranfers into a file in order to distinguish them better.

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Please provide your `rsync` command [in the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/512571/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, these failed transfers are printed to standard error (stderr) rather than stdout, though by default your shell will be printing both of these to your screen and the errors can be lost in the wall of text.

In order to capture just the errors, redirect file descriptor 2 (stderr) to a real file:

```bsh
rsync -options /source/* /destination/ 2>rsync-errors.txt
```